# onchange event fires after onmousedown event

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a jQuery and Ajax to dynamically generate the form elements.
so accordingly my code generates the elements and all working fine.

now I have an `onchange` event on each textbox which fires on focus out with value changed.

Also, I have a save button which has an `onmousedown` event to post the form data.

Code I am using:

(HTML code)

```
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" class="vchange" />
    <input type="text" class="vchange" />

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success vsubmit" onmousedown="return false;">Submit</a>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form').on('change', '.vchange input[type=text]', function () {
            //ajax post back code to save textbox data in database.
        });
        $('#form').on('mousedown', '.vsubmit', function () {
            $("#form").change(); //updated code as per suggestion
            let choice = confirm("Are you sure u want to submit the form?");
            if (choice) ? alert('Thank you.') : alert('cancelled.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, the problem is the `mousedown` event is called before the `onchange` event and so the data is not saved in the table.

Comment: so basically you are trying to save the values from the text box before you submit the form ?

Comment: yes.a kind of, as the form is very big with lots of interdependent elements and user is free to add n-number of fields to the form.

Comment: just updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a variable for your event-function. I've called it here "event". The variable "event" presents the element, which has triggered the event. In this case the even is "onmousemove". Thus you can gain access to its content, such as the value, by using "event.target.value" for example. This event actually occures, whenever you move your mouse above this element, no matter if the mouse button is clicked or not. But since its value doesn't change, when you don't press the mousebutton or move the slider, you won't see any changes. But it triggers though. You see the changes first, when you let it show the value of the slider or do something else, which changes by every triggering of that function.

This is the solution you're searching for:

```
$('#myrange').on('mousemove', function(event){
    $('#labelToShow').html(event.target.value);
    $('#inputWithTypeNumber').val(event.target.value);
})
```

and this is a code example for you to understand how it works

```
var somecounter = 0;
$('#myrange').on('mousemove', function(event){
    $('#labelToShow').html(somecounter++);
});
```

simply create an input element of the type "range" and give it the id "myrange". Then also create a label with the id "labelToShow" and another input element of type "number" with the id "inputWithTypeNumber". Like this.

```
<input type="range" id="myrange" />
<input type="number" id="inputWithTypeNumber" />
<label id="labelToShow">Move your mouse above the slider</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

so far i understood your problem is to save the values in the `textinput` with `ajax` call before you submit the form and the `mousedown` event fires before the `onchange` then why dont you trigger the `onchange` inside the `mousedown` event manually for a workaround like below

`$("#form").onchange();` or `$("#form").fireEvent("onchange");`

**EDIT**

I just thought to add the sample code so that if the OP is having problem understanding the idea i was discussing as a comment was just posted that the problem still isnt solved, what i am saying is that you can track the change for the text inputs with on change and to tackle the problem of the `mousedown` event to be always triggered after the `onchange` is to trigger the `onchange` inside the `mousedown` manually, like `$('input[class="vchange"]').trigger('change');` and you have wrong selector in your code for the `onchange` event `'.vchange input[type=text]'` this wont select any element either use `.vchange` or `'input[class="vchange"]'`. See below a demo where the form will always be submitted after sending ajax call.

**But keep in mind this will trigger simultanious ajax calls for every input with class `.vchange`** that has some value in it means it is not empty. so a better approach would be to create a separate function that collect all fields with class `.vchange` that has `value!==''` and send one call to save them all if you have numerous fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', 'input[class="vchange"]', function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      console.log('ajax post back code to save textbox data in database.');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('mousedown', '.vsubmit', function() {
    $('input[class="vchange"]').trigger('change');
    console.log('submitting form');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <input type="text" class="vchange" />
  <input type="text" class="vchange" />

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success vsubmit" onmousedown="return false;">Submit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: but how can i get the control of which textbox the value was changed as there are many textbox and they are dynamically added as per user needs.Also both the events are triggered as mousedown first and then onchange event later. no events are skipped.

Comment: hmm , that might be something that needs attention.

Comment: i tried this solution but still onchange event is triggered after click or mousedown event.

Comment: @Lalitkumar.annaldas can you update your post with the latest code you tried , it would rather become easier for me to troubleshoot

Comment: i have updated the code...please check it.I cant share the ajax side code as it calls the server for json response which is used to set value in another element.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you took for the above code..and also you got it right what i exactly wanted. But there is a catch for the above solution. what if i already have a value in text box which i wanted to change it to blank...then value!= blank will not update the textbox value in my database table during ajax call.

Comment: Well in that case my question would be , Why would I, You  or anyone would hit the submit button if he still wants some values to be changed?

Comment: and the `value!==''` was added so that the ajax call is not sent for the inputs that have no value so that extra ajax calls could be reduced

Comment: The reason i m doing post back for each onchange is bcoz i am validating the data entered by user whether the value is valid or whether the user is allowed to use the value and so i m saving the data onchange if the data is correct. After all the field is filled when the user hits the submit button the entry will go for approval.

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle the input in the same handler you ask the user to confirm?
If you use a form-element, you can use the submit event and think about a submit button to support keyboard only input.

```js
$(function(){

  $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let choice=confirm("Are you sure u want to submit the form?");
    
    if (!choice) {
      console.info("cancel");
    } else {
      console.info("ajax post back code to save textbox data in database.");
    }
  });
    
  $('.vsubmit').on('click', function () {
    $("#form").submit();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input type="text" class="vchange"/>
  <input type="text" class="vchange"/>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success vsubmit" onmousedown="return false;">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: there isnt an actual form i think the `id` `form` is on the `div`

Comment: dude but what about the onchange event of textbox.It should be triggered first and then the mousedown event

Comment: correct muhammad. there is no form. its just a id. To be clear i m trying to makee my client side elements as server side elements.

Comment: Ok so there is no way to change to a form, and the change event is really required before the user clicks the button?

Comment: yes. Thats the only way i can do the task. Else the combination of onchange event and onclick event requires to click the button twice.

Comment: Hm I don't get it, sorry to ask again - you want to send the data to the server before the user clicks, just on a change of value by user input? Then I would suggest using input-Event, not the change-Event.

Comment: hitting the backend for every input means keypress which is causing flicker on every character entry. Sorry i cant go for it.